# I am getting Pydantic Import Error: Base settings have been moved even after using ydata profiling

Tags: python, pandas, importerror, pydantic

**This is my code.**
`from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport as pf`

**This is the Error**

```
PydanticImportError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport as pf

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\__init__.py:7
      1 """Main module of ydata-profiling.
      2 
      3 .. include:: ../../README.md
      4 """
      5 import importlib.util
----> 7 from ydata_profiling.compare_reports import compare
      8 from ydata_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
      9 from ydata_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\compare_reports.py:9
      6 import pandas as pd
      7 from dacite import from_dict
----> 9 from ydata_profiling.config import Correlation, Settings
     10 from ydata_profiling.model import BaseDescription
     11 from ydata_profiling.model.alerts import Alert

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\config.py:7
      4 from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Tuple, Union
      6 import yaml
----> 7 from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseSettings, Field, PrivateAttr
     10 def _merge_dictionaries(dict1: dict, dict2: dict) -> dict:
     11     """
     12     Recursive merge dictionaries.
     13 
   (...)
     16     :return: Merged dictionary
     17     """

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\__init__.py:210, in __getattr__(attr_name)
    208 dynamic_attr = _dynamic_imports.get(attr_name)
    209 if dynamic_attr is None:
--> 210     return _getattr_migration(attr_name)
    212 from importlib import import_module
    214 module = import_module(_dynamic_imports[attr_name], package=__package__)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_migration.py:289, in getattr_migration.<locals>.wrapper(name)
    287     return import_string(REDIRECT_TO_V1[import_path])
    288 if import_path == 'pydantic:BaseSettings':
--> 289     raise PydanticImportError(
    290         '`BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. '
    291         f'See https://docs.pydantic.dev/{version_short()}/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings '
    292         'for more details.'
    293     )
    294 if import_path in REMOVED_IN_V2:
    295     raise PydanticImportError(f'`{import_path}` has been removed in V2.')

PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/u/import-error
```

The only thing I tried was to import ydata-profiling library. I was expecting this library to work by using **ydata-profiling** since **Pandas-profiling** is outdated and Pydantic has launched its verion 2.
I am trying to perform Exploratory Data Analysis on it(EDA).

Comment: This is a typical error for a version mismatch

Comment: Can you post the `__version__` of relevant libraries?

Comment: Specifically, ydata-profiling seems to expect a different version of pydantic than you have. Try to upgrade pydantic via pip

Comment: I upgraded Pydantic but it still didn't work. Turns out Jupyter Notebook has a library of its own that was supposed to be embedded to allow the latest version of Pydantic to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of ydata_profiling only works with an older pydantic version. From the link in your stacktrace:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/errors/usage_errors/#import-error

> This error is raised when you try to import an object that was
> available in Pydantic V1, but has been removed in Pydantic V2.
>
> See the Migration Guide for more information.

If upgrading ydata_profiling to the latest version does not fix it, you need to downgrade your pydantic-version. I strongly advise using `venv` to manage your python packages if such tricks are necessary in your codebase.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I sort of did this the other way around because I found out that I had to also install a Jupyter Notebook library because even that wasn't allowing some of the functions to work.

Comment: @KarthikKumarP it is allowed and encouraged to answer your own question if you found a solution.